# Blazor onclick event passing in counter from loop

Tags: c#, .net-core, single-page-application, blazor

I'm currently implementing table paging via a home grown solution in Blazor and coming across some difficulty. The troublesome piece of code is below (this is for rendering the paging buttons below a grid):

```
@for (int i = 0; i < vm.TotalPages; i++)
{
    <button id="pg-button-@i" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button"
        onclick="@(() => GetTablePage(i))">@i</button>
}
```

Notice in the onclick event, I am calling a function and passing in `i`, the counter for the current interation of the loop.

The `GetTablePage` method looks as follows:

```
protected async Task GetTablePage(int page)
{
    Console.WriteLine("page number: " + page);
}
```

My issue is that EVERY button will call this function with `i` set as the length of `vm.TotalPages`.

Here is an example to try to make this more clear:

View Markup (notice the `id` of each button is set appropriately):

```
<button id="pg-button-0" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button">0</button>
<button id="pg-button-1" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button">1</button>
<button id="pg-button-2" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button">2</button>
<button id="pg-button-3" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button">3</button>
<button id="pg-button-4" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button">4</button>
<button id="pg-button-5" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button">5</button>
<button id="pg-button-6" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button">6</button>
```

Upon clicking ANY of these buttons, my `GetTablePage` function is writing `7` to the console which is the length of the `vm.TotalPages` collection.

Why is this happening and how can I overcome it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Because `i` is a variable and the for loop is always finished when you click, it is 7 on that moment

You need to do something like:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < vm.TotalPages; i++)
{
    var tempint = i;
    <button id="pg-button-@i" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button"
        onclick="@(() => GetTablePage(tempint))">@i</button>
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This is a standard C# behavior where the lambda expression @(() => GetTablePage(i)) has access to a variable and not to the value of the variable, the result of which is that the lambda expression always calls GetTablePage(i) and i equals 7 at the end of the loop.  To solve this you can define a variable scoped locally to the loop like the following:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < vm.TotalPages; i++)
{
    var temp = i;
    <button id="pg-button-@temp " class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button"
        onclick="@(() => GetTablePage(temp ))">@temp </button>
}
```

Hope this helps...